# How to list all sessions in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there a way to enumarate trough all active blazor sessions (not http session) and for example list all active users?

*EDIT:
user is `AuthenticationState.User` retrieved by  `IAuthenticationStateProvider` scoped service or `<AuthorizeView>` component

Comment: What authentication system are you using? What do you mean by `users`, logged ones or everyone on your web application?

Comment: @AleksaRistic: Authentication mechanism should not matter, since they all works with `IPrincipal` and the Identity framework, but I'm using cookie authentication.